# System.Drawing.Image.Save throws ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI

Tags: .net, exception, gdi+, tiff

I have function which takes a bitmap, copies part of it and saves it as 8bpp tiff. Filename of the result image is unique and file doesn't exist, program has permission to write to the target folder.

```
void CropImage(Bitmap map) {
        Bitmap croped = new Bitmap(200, 50);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(croped)) {
            g.DrawImage(map, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 50), ...);
        }

        var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(2);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth, 8L);
        encoderParams.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionNone);

        croped.Save(filename, tiffEncoder, encoderParams);
        croped.Dispose();
    }
```

Weird thing is that this funcion works well on some computers (Win 7) and throws System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI exception on other computers (mostly Win XP).

All computers have the .NET 3.5 SP1 runtime installed.

If I use `croped.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Tiff);` instead `croped.Save(filename, tiffEncoder, encoderParams);` than it works on all computers, but I need to save Tiff in 8bpp format.

Do you have any ideas, where the problem could be?

Thanks, Lukas

Comment: maybe the picture is not yet saved, and begins to be disposed?

Comment: Are there any Windows XP machines that it works on?

Comment: GDI+ got updated to version 1.1 in Vista.  I never found any docs that describes the changes.  Sounds like you found one.

Comment: (moved answer from OP to comment): SLaks: I have tested it on two Wn XP computers and neither one worked.

Comment: Since your code looks perfectly OK... what about "tiffEncoder"... could the problem be there?

Comment: Did u solve it? I have a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381768/c-sharp-image-cant-be-opened-in-windows-xp-but-same-code-works-in-windows-7#10381768

Comment: @Lukas Kabrt Were you able to find the cause to this issue and a solution?

Comment: No I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

GDI is a windows operating system functionality. I encountered similar issues when dealing with 16-bit TIFF files, and resorted to a different library. See [using LibTIFF from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041783/using-libtiff-from-c-to-access-tiled-tiff-images)

The MSDN help suggest that the functionality is available, but at then Windows throws 'generic error' exceptions when you try to copy a bitmap into a new bitmap, or save it to a file or stream. Indeed the same functionality works well on Windows7 (which seems to have good TIFF support). See [New WIC functioanity in Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee720061%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The other solution I have used is to make a unsafe copy in 8-bit. This way I was able to save PNG files (with palette). I have not tried this for TIFF.

```
       // part of a function taking a proprietary TIFF tile structure as input and saving it into the desired bitmap format
      // tile.buf is a byterarray, containing 16-bit samples from TIFF.

        bmp = new Bitmap(_tile_width, _tile_height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        BitmapData bmpData =bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,bmp.PixelFormat);
        int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;

        dstBitsPalette = (byte *)bmpData.Scan0;

        offset=0;


        for (offset = 0; offset < _tile_size; offset += 2)
        {
             dstBitsPalette[offset >> 1] = tile.buf[offset + 1];
        }

        // setup grayscale palette
        ColorPalette palette = bmp.Palette;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            Color c = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
            palette.Entries[i] = c;
        }
        bmp.Palette = palette;
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        return bmp;

    }
```